# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint on linked record when add a record using the entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, constraints, primary-key

I have a table called `farmers`. Each farmer has a country specified that is mandatory.

When I add a new farmer to the database using antity framework, I get a violation on the country table. It looks like the entity framework wants to add the country to the country table, but I only want the guid in my farmer table:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Country'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Country'.   The statement has been
>   terminated.

Can somebody advise me on what I'm doing wrong? here the code for the insert:

```
        newFarmer.Guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        ents.Farmer.AddObject(newFarmer);
        ents.SaveChanges();
        return newFarmer;
```

I even checked the state of the country and it says unchanged.

Comment: Add structure of these 2 entities and tables to question.

Comment: The most important part in your code snippet is missing: Where do get the `Country` object from that you assign to `newFarmer.Country`? Normally one would immediately guess that your `Country` object isn't attached to the ObjectContext when you call `AddObject(newFarmer)` which would cause an INSERT of the `Country` object. But then its state could not be `unchanged` as you say. The exception you have is - with an object in state `unchanged` - pretty impossible. Some important info must be missing in your problem description and code.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is that Entity Framework doesn't understand that your entity primary key is also the identity and should be auto-incremented. I had the same problem in an application using EF 4.1 with database first.  To solve the problem, I had to::

- Make sure my entities primary key had a name "ID" (to avoid putting a decorator [Key] above my Model class.
- Make sure the property option "Identity" of your database system (SQL Server in my case) is set to "Yes".

Then, my EF4.1 was able to do the insert and update of my entities.

Hope this helps!